# take 4*4 matrix from user to test if it includes 2*2 sub-matrix have the same value

Tags: c++

i just need the user to enter 4*4 matrix of character, the out put will be yes or no according to if there is a 2 * 2 sub-matrix have the same input.
the code is always print false.

**the code is:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //input
    char color[4][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cin >> color[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    //for testing if there are a squar  
    // * * * *
    // * * # #
    // # # * *
    // * * # #
    
    // 'yes' as
    // * * 
    // * *
    // is a squar of 2*2
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (j != 3) {
                if (color[i][j] == color[i][j + 1] == color[i + 1][j] == color[i + 1][j + 1]) {
                    cout << "yes";
                    break;
                }
                else cout << "no";
            }
        }
    }

    //for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        //for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            //if (j == 3)
                //cout << colors[i][j] <<"\n";
            //else
            //cout << colors[i][j];
        //}
    //}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: `a == b == c == d` does not do what you think it does. It is interpreted as `((a == b) == c) == d`, which means you are comparing intermediate result (`true` or `false`) with a `char`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition is wrong:

```
if (color[i][j] == color[i][j + 1] == color[i + 1][j] == color[i + 1][j + 1]
```

For simplicity, consider

```
if (a == b == c)
```

which is parsed as

```
if ( (a == b) == c)
```

The result of `a==b` is compared to `c`. The result of `a==b` is either `true` or `false` which can be converted to `1` or `0`, respectively.

You would get `"yes"` printed on the screen when there is a 2x2 submatrix with all elements equal to `1`, though it would be for the wrong reasons.

What you actually want is:

```
if ( a==b && a==c)
```

Do not ignore your compilers warnings! With the right flags, your code does not compile: https://godbolt.org/z/45oqcTEna.

Moreover, the loop goes outof bounds of the array. You prevent `j` going out of bounds but when `i == 3` then `color[i + 1][j]` is trying to access an element that does not exist. Instead of iterating till `<4` and then excluding `j == 3`, let the loop only iterate indices that are valid upper left corners of the submatrix:

```
const size_t size = 4;
const size_t sub_matrix_size = 1;
for (size_t i=0; i < size-sub_matrix_size; ++i) {
     for (size_t j=0; j < size-sub_matrix_size; ++j) {
        //...
```